# How to get the current Firefox profile path from within my applet?

Tags: java, firefox, applet

I'm using [Network Security Services for Java (JSS) by Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/jss/) in my applet in order to allow some low-level interaction between my (signed) Java Applet and Mozilla Firefox.

One of the first problem I'm facing is how to find the current Firefox profile path. I need it because I have to call the [initialize(String configDir)](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/jss/javadoc/org/mozilla/jss/CryptoManager.html#initialize%28java.lang.String%29) method of CryptoManager, and the so-called configDir has to be the directory of a Firefox profile.

How can I grab the full path of the current Firefox profile? Is there a clean way or I have to go reading profiles.ini in {$APPDATA}/Firefox, parse it and then choose a random profile (hoping it's only one, or the one I get is the correct one)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's actually possible to start Firefox without reading profiles.ini, so that's not reliable. The only reliable way I know involves the XPCOM directory service, but I don't know whether you have access to that.

Comment: I have access to everything a Java program can access, even JNI. (this is a signed applet)

Comment: So could you write a JNI class that's also an XPCOM binary extension?

Comment: I don't know what XPCOM is, I'll dig into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript you can obtain profile and Executable directory:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');

var profile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path

var CurProcD = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("CurProcD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path
```

Comment: Perfect, but how could I pass the profile as a parameter to the applet?

Comment: Now, how can I call this sentence from a Java Applet `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path`

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at **section 1.3.2** here:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Using_the_JavaScript_or_Error_Console

Hope that helps.

Comment: The tricks works from within Firefox Console, but not as a standard javascript (it would pose security issues). How can I in some way employ it in my applet?